# How can I store new Date().getTime() in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

How can I store new Date().getTime() in mongodb? Its being stored as double value.

Example: when I store 1398856176723 , its being stored as 1398856176723.0000 and type as double

Comment: You can insert the `Date` object and Mongo will store it to a timestamp.

Comment: How you are trying to store ? Are you using mongo shell ? If you are using mongo shell use NumberInt() method for 32-bit interger .

Comment: @Sumeet , actually I am using nodejs mongodb native to store.

Comment: Why don't you want to store it as a `Date` like @Sebastian correctly suggests?

Comment: @JohnnyHK , its a cross platform app..Java edition stores it as Int64. So I need to store as int64 in JS too.

Comment: That's how it's stored internally by MongoDB when you store is as a `Date` in JavaScript.  MongoDB will store a JS `Date` as a platform independent BSON Date which can be accessed as a `java.util.Date` in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Just insert the date object and MongoDB will store it correctly (including timezone information).